# Is it possible to prevent repeated location usage warning prompts in iOS 13?

Tags: privacy, geolocation, ios

I have a couple of apps which I have set to Always On location usage. I'm sure that's what I want, and it's not going to change any time soon. iOS 13 prompts me about each of them every day or two. I would like to disable these prompts. Is there any way to do that currently?

Comment: I don't think that still happens.

Comment: I still get some repeat requests, but many fewer than before.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is currently not possible as of iOS 13.

You should expect to get 1 permission request the first time you run the app.

You'll get one more if the app needs background permission.

You might get one more after several days of using the app.  This is so iOS can validate you still want it to have background, always allow permission.  After that, if you allow it location permission, you shouldn't receive any more notifications.

That means, in total, you could receive up to 3 notifications per app.  After that, the same app shouldn't notify you or ask permission again unless the developer changed the permission request in code.

Comment: It asks me about Google Maps just about every week. It's getting more than a little irritating:\

Comment: Certainly not what is happening for me. It never stops repeating the request.

Comment: That's strange.  I haven't had a repeated request for any app and I use a lot of apps that need location, including Waze and Google Maps.